# Foreseen consequences of accidents caused during a fully driverless service

Tags: arizona, accident

[Waymo](https://waymo.com) has just opened its fully driverless service to the general public in Phoenix. What happens if such a car crosses the red light and causes a deadly crash? Who and what punishment will be given for not following the rules and causing the death of one person?

Comment: Is it currently legal for driverless vehicles to drive on Arizona's roads?

Comment: @SJuan76: [link](https://blog.waymo.com/2020/10/waymo-is-opening-its-fully-driverless.html)